# From edit to update how to link between them?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to get from my edit page to my update page but there is nothing in the documentation that's explaining how to route to it. This is my form on my edit page:

```
/*
Or method="PUT"
*/
<form method="PATCH" action="../{{$id}}">
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
<input type="submit" value="edit"/>
</form>
```

My routes is being declared as a resource controller:

```
Routes::resource('/','TestController',['parameters' => [
    '' => 'test'
]]);
```

In my controller I just have:

```
public function update(Request $request, Test $test){
    return 'test';
}
```

It's just giving me different errors when trying to access the update action in multiple ways.

I tried: `{{route($id)}}` which gives me:

> Route 1 not defined

The resource documentation gives me that the url is suppose to be like this:

```
PUT/PATCH   /photos/{photo}
```

I dont understand the routing of resource controllers in laravel and theres not a lot to find about it. I even tried to simply go 1 back from `/{{$id}}/edit` like this: `../{{$id}}`but that just brings me to the show action(since show and update have the same url apparently) and I also think this isnt the best way to access an action from the controller.

Comment: You've not provided an action for the form.

Comment: @RossWilson Yeah I kept that empty cause the example underneath it is what I've tried as an action

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form opening tag to be:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url($id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works but why. I dont get why my other attempt at getting to $id didnt work.

Comment: @Loko because you were using `route()`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route

Answer (score 0):

for a resource route you can have following methods in controller.
Index

```
public function index()
    {
        return view();
    }
```

Create

```
public function create()
    {
        //
    }
```

Store

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }
```

show

```
public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }
```

Edit

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }
```

Update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }
```

Destroy

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
```

Create your controller using php artisan. then those resource methods will create automatically.

Comment: This is not what Im talking about

Comment: if this is a edit from do the route model binding. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: write your save code inside store method. for resource route edit url is like  http://homedomain.com/route/id/edit